# Magento 2: Send email to admin after wholesaler customer register

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3

I have created custom form in which the only wholesaler can do registration, I want to do when wholesaler customer can registered admin can get the email that wholesaler register, please let me know how can I do that?

Comment: @Sumit if you know how to do it please let me know

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by adding send email functionality to your wholesaler customer registration action (controller).

You can follow below step by step guide to add send email functionality into your code.

[How to create send email functionality](https://www.brainacts.com/blog/magento-2-how-to-send-email-programmatically)